# Swing, resize then draw

Tags: java, image, swing

I have an image that is to be drawn on a JFrame. The dimensions of the image are dependent on the dimensions of the JFrame.

The JFrame is drawn significantly more often then the JFrame is actually re-sized. Thus I had the image re-sized then stored in the component re-size event and only drew the re-sized image in the draw method.

```
//called on componentResized
private void scaleImage(){
    if((this.getHeight() * this.getWidth()) != 0)
        scalledBackGroundImage = backGroundImage.getScaledInstance(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_FAST);
    else
    scalledBackGroundImage = null;
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    if(scalledBackGroundImage != null)
        g.drawImage(scalledBackGroundImage, 0, 0, this);

    super.paint(g);
}
```

However I would seem that the re-size event is called after paint when a component is redrawn. Thus the image displayed is the image  for the previous frame size. This really becomes a problem with actions like maximize or minimize.

I am looking for a way to detect a JFrame re-size before paint is called.
(I know I could call repaint() on re-size but it seem a bit rude to ask for the component to be drawn twice when re-sizing)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: In this situation, I would avoid trying to resize the image every time the component is resized, as conceivability, `componentResized` may be called a number of times before the actual size of the component is realized.  Instead.  I add a `javax.swing.Timer` with a short delay (may be 125 milliseconds) and `restart` it each time the method is called.  When the timer is triggered, I actually resize the image.  This reduces the number of times I might need to resize the image down to a more reasonable amount, saving time and memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html). It really is not a very good choice.

Not only do you have the problem you described above, but I get a lot of flickering:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ResizeSSCCE extends JPanel
{
    Image original;
    Image scaled;

    public ResizeSSCCE()
    {
        original = new ImageIcon( "mong.jpg" ).getImage();
        scaled = original;
        scaleImage();

        ComponentListener cl = new ComponentAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
            {
                scaleImage();
            }
        };

        addComponentListener(cl);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        if (scaled != null)
            g.drawImage(scaled, 0, 0, this);
//          g.drawImage(original, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }

    private void scaleImage()
    {
        if (getHeight() * getWidth() != 0)
            scaled = original.getScaledInstance(getWidth(), getHeight(), Image.SCALE_FAST);
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ResizeSSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new ResizeSSCCE() );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Change the code to use your image and then run using the scaled version to see the flickering. Then change the code to use the original image that is scale of the fly to see the difference. As the article suggests scaling on the fly is the better approach.

Comment: Agree. Stop worrying and learn to love (trust) the double buffering of Swing components. :-) Pro tip: Make sure you use a compatible image, otherwise the scaling will be slow whatever way you do it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a component listener to JFrame as

```
 jFrame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
               //Your resize method here
            }
        });
```

Comment: I could be wrong (the question is a little unclear), but I though that's what the OP was doing...